# Splitting a string based on regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

Need to split a string which is a combination of different materials. Need to extract all the materials by using a reg expression.

Possible inputs are

```
 65%POLYESTER 30%COTTON 5%WOOL
 95% COTTON DENIM 5% OTHERS
 100% HS POLYPROPYLENE
 100% POLYPROPYLENE HEATSET
```

Outputs should be

```
65% Polyester
30% Cotton
5% wool
```

Tried this

```
static IList<string> SplitContent(string input)
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            var regex = new Regex("\\d*\\.\\d+%?[A-Za-z \\s]");
            var matches = regex.Matches(input);
            foreach (Match item in matches)
            {
                list.Add(item.Value);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

But it is not returning any matches. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a better way would be

```
List<string> output=Regex.Matches(yourInput,@"\d+(\.\d+)?%?[a-zA-Z\s]+")
                         .Cast<Match>()
                         .Select(x=>Regex.Replace(x.Value,@"(%)(?=\S)","$1 "))
                         .ToList();
```

---

`\d+` matches 1 to many digits

`(\.\d+)?` matches a dot and 1 to many digits 0 to 1 time(`?`)

`[a-zA-Z\s]+` matches any character within that class 1 to many times..

The match would break when there is a character which is not `[a-zA-Z\s]` or when you come to end of the string

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: Can you explain your regular expression a bit?

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: If I need to place space after the %value, how can I do that? For example, '65%POLYESTER' should become like '65% POLYESTER'

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ:..ohh gosh, you missed the most confusing part

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ:   please explain this:  +(\.\d+)?%?

Comment: @BhushanFirake `\d+(\.\d+)?%?` would allow matches like `33%` `33.33` `333` `2.2%`..so i made `%` optional..`(\.\d+)` optional with `?`

Comment: +1, but you don't need the `Singleline` option.  It changes the meaning of the dot (`.`) metacharacter, allowing it to match any character *including* linefeed (`\n`).  The only dot in your regex is escaped in order to match a literal dot, so `Singleline` has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

Make the decimal separator `.` optional, and change the description part to "anything but space", like this:

```
var regex = new Regex("\\d*(?:\\.)?\\d+%?[^\\s]+");
```

The rest of your program works fine, and does not require any modifications ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/WVtCud)).

Comment: It is returning only the %values. It's not returning the associate material with them. For example if I pass '95% COTTON DENIM 5% OTHERS', it is returning 95% and 5%. But the expected output is '95% COTTON DENIM' and '5% OTHERS'

Comment: Changed it to '\\d*(?:\\.)?\\d+%?[*A-Za-z\\s]+', and it is returning along with associated values. Thanks.

Comment: @Naresh I would highly recommend using verbatim strings: `@"\d*(?:\.)?\d+%?[*A-Za-z\s]+"`. Also (@dasblinkenlight) `[^\s] == \S` and (this is just an alternative suggestion, choose whichever you think is more easily readable) one can write `[.]` instead of `\.`.

Comment: [^\\s] is not considering the string if there is any space immediately after the percentage value. It is moving to next percentage value.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string ip = "65%POLYESTER 30%COTTON 5%WOOL 95%COTTON DENIM 5%OTHERS 100%HS POLYPROPYLENE 100%POLYPROPYLENE HEATSET";
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        lst = SplitContent(ip);
        foreach (var item in lst)
        {
            string[] arr=item.Split('%');

            Console.WriteLine(arr[0]+"% "+arr[1]);
        }
```

In your SplitContent Function you have got the regular expression incorrect.It should be as below:

```
     public static List<string> SplitContent(string input)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        var regex = new Regex("\\d*\\%[A-Za-z]*");
        var matches = regex.Matches(input);
        foreach (Match item in matches)
        {
            list.Add(item.Value);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Hope this helps...!!